# error: object xml is not a member of package com.databricks.spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-sql, scala-xml

I am trying to read XML file using SBT but i am facing issue when i compile it.

build.sbt

```
name:= "First Spark"
version:= "1.0"
organization := "in.goai"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-avro_2.10" % "2.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.2"
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
```

.scala file

```
package in.goai.spark

import scala.xml._
import com.databricks.spark.xml
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

object SparkMeApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("First Spark")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val fileName = args(0)
    val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "book").load("fileName")
    val selectedData = df.select("title", "price")
    val d = selectedData.show
    println(s"$d")

  }
}
```

when i compile it by giving "sbt package" it shows bellow error

```
[error] /home/hadoop/dev/first/src/main/scala/SparkMeApp.scala:4: object xml is not a member of package com.databricks.spark
[error] import com.databricks.spark.xml
[error]        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 9 s, completed Sep 22, 2017 4:11:19 PM
```

Do i need to add any other jar files related to xml? please suggest and please provide me any link which gives information about jar files for different file formats

Comment: you can refer https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.0, in `build.sbt`, change your dependencies to the following:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "3.2.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" %% "spark-xml" % "0.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"
```

1. Change the `spark-avro` version to 3.2.0: https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro#requirements
2. Add `"com.databricks" %% "spark-xml" % "0.4.1"`: https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#scala-211
3. Change the `scala-xml` version to 1.0.6, the current version for Scala 2.11: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.11

In your code, delete the following import statement:

```
import com.databricks.spark.xml
```

Note that your code doesn't actually use the `spark-avro` or `scala-xml` libraries. Remove those dependencies from your `build.sbt` (and the `import scala.xml._` statement from your code) if you're not going to use them.

Comment: I am able to compile now :) but when i execute it it shows me below error
any idea?

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType$.Unlimited()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType;

Comment: @ashoksrinivas: In your `sbt` console, run `reload` and `update`.

Comment: Sorry chunjef i am new to sbt and learning myself. i dont know how to console, reload, run sbt...i request you to guide me 

Thanks

Comment: i give " sbt package " folowed by this code to run "  spark-submit --master "local[*]" --class in.goai.spark.SparkMeApp /home/hadoop/devo/first/target/scala-2.11/first-spark_2.11-1.0.jar scala.xml "

Comment: @ashoksrinivas: Try running `sbt clean reload update`.

Comment: Tried but no result :(

Comment: You should probably reward @ashoksrinivas the answer and start a new question for the `NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType` issue.