# Why does spark-xml fail with NoSuchMethodError with Spark 2.0.0 dependency?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-xml

Hi I am a noob to Scala and Intellij and I am just trying to do this on Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlReader


object SparkSample {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new spark.SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName("Datasets Test")
    conf.setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new spark.SparkContext(conf)

    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    val df = sqlContext.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "shop")
      .load("shops.xml") /* NoSuchMethod error here */

    val selectedData = df.select("author", "_id")
  df.show
}
```

Basically I am trying to convert XML into spark dataframe
I am getting a NoSuchMethod error in '.load("shops.xml")'
 the Below is the SBT

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.3"
val sparkVersion = "2.0.0" 
val sparkXMLVersion = "0.3.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark"      %%  "spark-core"      %   sparkVersion  exclude("jline", "2.12"),
  "org.apache.spark"      %% "spark-sql"        % sparkVersion excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "jline"),ExclusionRule("name","2.12")),
   "com.databricks"        %% "spark-xml"        % sparkXMLVersion,
)
```

Below is the trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.types.DecimalType$.Unlimited()Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DecimalType;
at com.databricks.spark.xml.util.InferSchema$.<init>(InferSchema.scala:50)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.util.InferSchema$.<clinit>(InferSchema.scala)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(XmlRelation.scala:46)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(XmlRelation.scala:46)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.XmlRelation.<init>(XmlRelation.scala:45)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:66)
at com.databricks.spark.xml.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:44)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:315)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:132)
```

Can someone point out the error?Seems like a dependency issue to me.
spark-core seems to be working fine but not spark-sql 
I had scala 2.12 before but changed to 2.11 because spark-core was not resolved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: object xml is not a member of package com.databricks.spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369452/error-object-xml-is-not-a-member-of-package-com-databricks-spark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I think it's a Scala version mismatch issue. Use spark-xml **0.4.1**.

Quoting spark-xml's [Requirements](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml#requirements) (highlighting mine):

> This library requires Spark 2.0+ for 0.4.x.
>
> For version that works with **Spark 1.x**, please check for **branch-0.3**.

That says to me that spark-xml 0.3.3 works with Spark 1.x (not Spark 2.0.0 that you requested).